# Uploading image to spring rest service using Angular

Tags: angular, spring

I am trying to send an http request to my spring boot service with a x-wwww-form-urlencoded content type, but am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my angular code:

```
img(desc:HTMLInputElement, selectedFile){
    let url = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/upload_image"

    const body = new HttpParams()
    body.set("image", selectedFile)
    body.set("description", desc.value)

    return this.http.post<Isecurity[]>(url, body.toString(),{
      headers:new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    } )
  }
```

and this is my Spring service:

```
@PostMapping("upload_image")
@CrossOrigin
public  Map<String, Boolean> upload_image(@RequestParam MultipartFile image, @RequestParam String description) {
        Map<String, Boolean> values = new HashMap<>();
        values.put("response", true);
        return values;
}
```

I'm getting a 500 server error. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Send with FormData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are passing params in the wrong way. You just kept the name of params as body, but it is not actually the body.

You need to pass params using '?' after the url.

So you have to update your code in .ts file as the below lines:

```
img(desc:HTMLInputElement, selectedFile){
    let url = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/upload_image?"

    const body = new HttpParams()
    body.set("image", selectedFile)
    body.set("description", desc.value)

    return this.http.post<Isecurity[]>(url+body.toString(),{
      headers:new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    } )
  }
```

This was all about passing parameters, but I think you should take the image as the **body** and not as params in the rest api.

Comment: If the solution worked for you, please upvote too, so that it could be helpful for others also.